# Run a .net framework 1.1 program under .net framework 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-1.1, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to run the freeware version of codesmith (2.6, that has been built on .net framework 1.1) on Windows Server 2008 r2 64bit

There is a way to force it run under the .net framework 4.0?

The .net 1.1 installer says there are compatibility issues on my os

edit: I wanted to know if there is a way to decompile/recompile , like those hacks to add x64 compatibility to .net apps if it was flagged as 32bit only in visual studio

Comment: Unless you're doing something as crazy as developing on the actual server, then cant you do the codegen on a workstation or for .net 1.1 in a virtual machine if need be.

Comment: No, i need it once, and also the workstation it's windows 7 x64 that has the same incompatibilities.

Comment: @Magnetic_dud: Have you tried XP Mode for Windows 7?

Comment: Actually I don't like the XP mode, i feel it's an ugly hack based on hyperv+rdp. I prefer VirtualBox :P

Comment: @Magnetic_dud Ugly hack! You're the one trying to get a 10 year old copy of CodeSmith to work :P

Comment: @chibacity +1 Sometimes i'm just lazy, and I end to do much more work than the right way to do the stuff. Anyway I'm doing the VM way right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible

Just delete:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v1.1.4322" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v1.0.3705" />
    <requiredRuntime version="v1.0.3705" />
</startup>
```

from CodeSmith.exe.config, and it works flawlessly on .net framework 4.0 on x64 :-D

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend updating to the latest version that has been fully tested on the latest editions of Windows 64bit and .NET. Please contact [sales/support](http://www.codesmithtools.com/contactus) and we will work with you ;) and help get your templates updated if needed.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski

Comment: If I were a professional dev, I would follow that way, because there are lots of new functions, but I am just an hobbyist that needs to run someone else's templates just a few times

Comment: We work with hobbyist and all developers and there is a way to get it for free ;) Please contact us for more information. We would love to see you on the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Dot net 1.1 and 4.0 has many differences. There is a good number of API that has been changed. So, even if you could hack it to run on 4.0, it might be crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to Windows 8.1 actually removed previously installed Framework 1.1.

Deleting the  **<startup>** node in config file did not work for me,  however - changing that part in the **CodeSmith.exe.config** to:

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
</startup>
```

made it work on Framework 2.0 without the problem, so I was able to make changes on my old project.